# Batch renaming files in unix and rollback

Tags: linux, unix, shell, rename

I rename few files (`1234.xml`, `9876.xml`, `2345.xml` etc) with `.xml` extension with the following code :

```
 for i in *.xml  
 do  
 mv $i $i.ab  
 done
```

it becomes `1234.xml.ab`, `9876.xml.ab`, `2345.xml.ab`...etc

Now, I want to rename it to `1234.xml.SD`, `9876.xml.SD`, `2345.xml.SD`...etc.

These are 100 files.

How can this be achieved with the help of code ? Please advise.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash you can do:

```
for f in *.xml.ab; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.ab}.SD"
done
```

or just use the `rename` command as:

```
rename 's/ab$/SD/' *.xml.ab
```

Comment: But if your filenames had spaces it would fail without the `"`. So always enclose filenames in `"`.

Comment: Note that this `rename` command comes from a Perl distribution and is not a standard unix command. Debian (and derived distributions such as Ubuntu) ships it as part of its perl package, but it's unlikely to be available elsewhere.

Comment: Also, this needs to be `mv -- "$f" "${f%.ab}.SD"` unless you know that file names don't begin with a `-`.

Comment: @codaddict, ah, valuable tip :-)

Comment: @Gilles, you mean if the filename starts with -1234.xml.ab, then we should use mv -- "$f" "${f%.ab}.SD" to append it with "SD" ? Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @Ashish: Yes. Normally, an argument that begins with `-` is an option (or several options). For example here `mv` would consider `1`, `2`, and so on to be options. The argument `--` signals the end of options, so with `mv -- "$f" "${f%.ab}.SD"`, the value of `f` cannot be mistaken for an option. This is not specific to `mv`, most unix commands behave in this way. Therefore `--` is fairly common in well-written scripts (so that the script doesn't misbehave if a file name happens to begin with `-`).

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for well explained reason :-) Do you advise any good shell-script book which i can refer to :-) That should have well explained basic concepts, important tips, use of regex in scripting, talks about various shells, use of each command and its application :-)

Comment: @Ashish: No, sorry, I learnt by example and spec-reading, but I'd be incapable of explaining how to tell the good examples from the bad (shell scripting is full of pitfalls like the ones you've seen here). There are a couple of threads on the topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
for f in *.xml.ab; do
    mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/\.ab$//g'`
done
```

Comment: You need double quotes around variable and command substitutions, and `echo` is only reliable if the file name doesn't start with `-` and doesn't contain a backslash. `mv --- "$f" "$(printf %s "$f" | sed 's/\.ab$//g')"` would be ok, but [codaddict's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025438/batch-renaming-files-in-unix-and-rollback/4025499#4025499) is both conceptually simpler and easier to get right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear if you want to rename foo.xml.ab -> foo.xml or foo.xml.ab -> foo.xml.SD

**foo.xml.ab -> foo.xml**

```
for f in *.xml.ab; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.ab}"
done
```

**foo.xml.ab -> foo.xml.SD**

```
for f in *.xml.ab; do
    mv "$f" "${f/.ab/.SD}"
done
```

Comment: it the second code that you wrote [foo.xml.ab -> foo.xml.SD] im trying :-) Thanks